# Do I need to use Core Data if planning on using Ruby on Rails for IOS app?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift, core-data, backend

I am new to coding in general so this may be a silly question:

Do I need to use/implement Core Data if I am planning to use Ruby on Rails as a backend? For Example, can Ruby on Rails handle everything needed for object graphs, relationships, etc..?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: CoreData is only for the iOS side only. It has nothing to do with your Ruby on Rails backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is nothing required about Core Data. It is an object database library that integrates well with iOS and Mac OS, but Ruby on Rails does not depend on it. Given that Rails is not Apple specific and Core Data **is** Apple specific, it wouldn't make sense for Rails to depend on Core Data.

I haven't used Rails before, but it looks like you can use SQLite or MySQL with Rails.

Comment: Thank you so much Duncan! Much appreacited!